# WAMP: How to protect a specific file?

Tags: file, wamp

Recently, I have downloaded Wamp Server 2.5 on Windows 7, and I have made a file called test in www directory which has 2 files

( www/test/ )

- index.php (which uses test.css in the same file)
- test.css

The problem is everyone can see what's inside test.css by adding test.css to the url and the code will appear. How can I protect this file from being shown to anyone?

Comment: Why do you want to hide your css file? If you restrict access to your file, the website will not be layouted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it.

The browser must be able to download it, hence it's available to everyone.

And mind you, it's not even a problem. It's just a css file.